# how to get better result from python OpenCV Thresholding?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an original image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBamY.jpg), and i want to segment each character on this lisence plate later, i use gaussian threshold to transform the plate before i segment each character with this code:

```
Val_hsv = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(crop_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))[1]
    adaptive_tresh = threshold_local(Val_hsv, 29, offset=9, method="gaussian")
    thresh = (Val_hsv > adaptive_tresh).astype("uint8") * 255
    thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

    crop_frame = imutils.resize(crop_frame, width=400)
    thresh = imutils.resize(thresh, width=400)
    cv2.imshow("Threshold plate", thresh)
```

the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV4cU.jpg) that come out is too much noise i think, i'm confused, any solution for better result than this? thankyou

Comment: Try color segmentation using `cv2.inRange()` method, as your desired text is mainly composed of white color, so you should be able to just extract that color from the input image.

Comment: @ZdaR: sorry but this is a silly advice. Black and white are precisely "non-colors" (completely unsaturated) so working on color or grayscale makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` in this I would recommend simple color segmentation, using which you can easily segment out the black and red colored noise elements in the input image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

original_image = cv2.imread("/path/to/img.jpg")

mask = cv2.inRange(original_image, np.array([210, 210, 210]), np.array([255, 255, 255]))
```

[image]

You can optimize the results further by experimenting with various color domains such as HSV, etc. which will give you more fine control over the color thresholding bounds.